# risks of using a Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a question about Maven and it's dependencies
when using a certain dependency can present a danger for my project ? for example if the dependency is not reliable .
And could commons dependencies like JUNIT , ApachePOI etc ...that every project needs be a danger too ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on other people's code is dangerous from various perspectives.  Writing everything yourself (to avoid dependencies) is also dangerous from various perspectives.  Solution: you need to understand the dangers, weigh them up, and make up your mind.  And mitigate the dangers / risks that are most important to your project ... as best you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is much too broad, but in this general sense: Yes, drawing files from MavenCentral is potentially dangerous and it is your obligation to test them.

Comment: thanks , but what do you mean by testing them ? and how can I be sure that a certain dependency is reliable ?

Comment: You cannot be sure. You can use dependencies that are "common" and hope the best. And you can write enough automated tests to ensure the functionality you want.

Comment: I see , so we can only test the functionalities but we can not be sure that the dependency is safe to use

Comment: log4j2 changed everything I guess